# Losing edge values in last colormap subplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 1.5.3.

I'm doing some colormaps with the "y" axis shared.
The problem is that when placing the colorbar in the last subplot I lose the first and last tick on the x axis. But if you enlarge the figure (figsize = (12,3) for example) some white space appears at the edges of the other subplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.random.random((10, 10, 3))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3)) # Try a figsize=(12, 3)

for i in range(3):
    if i == 0:
        ay1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    else:
        plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1, sharey=ay1)
    plt.imshow(matrix[:, :, i], interpolation='nearest')
    if i == 2:
        plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sharey` only makes sense, if you use different sized images. But when the images are differently sized, in some parts of the figure there is nothing - which will be painted white.

On the other hand, if you do have same size pictures as here, there is no need to use `sharey`. In that case, you can simply plot your data and add a colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.random.random((10, 10, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(12, 3))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.85)
for i in range(3):
    im = ax[i].imshow(matrix[:, :, i], interpolation='nearest')
    ax[i].set_aspect("equal")

plt.draw()
p = ax[-1].get_position().get_points().flatten()
ax_cbar = fig.add_axes([0.9,p[1], 0.02, p[3]-p[1]] )
plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cbar)

plt.show()
```

[image]